# Create shareable link for all files in Dropbox using Dropbox API

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have around 100 files in my Dropbox account I am trying to make shareable link for all of the files using Dropbox API.

Tried using 
`DbxClient = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);`
client.createShareableUrl(path);
but got an error on `DbxClient` cannot find symbol, or class not found.

```
import com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.*;
import static com.dropbox.core.v2.files.AlphaGetMetadataError.path;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.FileMetadata;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.ListFolderResult;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.Metadata;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.RequestedVisibility;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.SharedLinkMetadata;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.SharedLinkSettings;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.users.FullAccount;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;



public class DBX {

    static boolean doYouWantMeToUpload = false;

    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "My access token here I removed it";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws DbxException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // Create Dropbox client
        DbxRequestConfig config = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("dropbox/java-tutorial").build();
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Get current account info
        FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();
        System.out.println(account.getName().getDisplayName());

        if(doYouWantMeToUpload == true){
            // Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
            ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("");
            while (true) {
                for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                    System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
                }

                if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                    break;
                }

                result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
            }

            // Upload "test.txt" to Dropbox
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
                FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("/test.txt")
                    .uploadAndFinish(in);
            }

            // Get shareable link for a file
            DbxClient = new DbxClient(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
            client.createShareableUrl(test.txt);



        }
    }
}
```

I want to get shareable link for all files in my Dropbox.
I followed these [instructions in Dropbox GitHub](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#dropbox-for-java-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to use the old `createShareableUrl` which is for Dropbox API v1, which is now retired.

You should instead use Dropbox API v2, via [`DbxClientV2`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxClientV2.html), like you do for the other calls in your code.

Specifically, to create a shared link, you should use [`createSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#createSharedLinkWithSettings-java.lang.String-). That would look something like:

```
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

client.sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings(path);
```